# why the app doesnt works after install react native navigation module?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

well, there is no error before I executed this command: "npm install @react-navigation/native". After I installed this module, when I execute app in android emulator react native app doesnt works. there is no problem on my node.js, npm, android_home,android sdk.

BUILD FAILED in 10s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform artifact 'react-native-reanimated-61.aar (project :react-native-reanimated)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-manifest}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\JohnH\Desktop\ReactNative Coding\ReactNative\react_native_navigation_01\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\react-native-reanimated-61.aar.
> > Failed to transform 'C:\Users\JohnH\Desktop\ReactNative Coding\ReactNative\react_native_navigation_01\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\react-native-reanimated-61.aar' using Jetifier. Reason: Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping(from=C:\Users\JohnH\Desktop\ReactNative Coding\ReactNative\react_native_navigation_01\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\react-native-reanimated-61.aar, to=C:\Users\JohnH\Desktop\ReactNative Coding\ReactNative\react_native_navigation_01\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\android\build.transforms\c66aa8e9da80f2493bdea3fa761dc58e\jetified-react-native-reanimated-61.aar)'. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

```
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:616:11)
at execFileSync (child_process.js:634:13)
at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\JohnH\Desktop\ReactNative Coding\ReactNative\react_native_navigation_01\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
at buildAndRun (C:\Users\JohnH\Desktop\ReactNative Coding\ReactNative\react_native_navigation_01\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:179:41)
at then.result (C:\Users\JohnH\Desktop\ReactNative Coding\ReactNative\react_native_navigation_01\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:133:12)
```

package.json
{
"name": "react_native_navigation_01",
"version": "0.0.1",
"private": true,
"scripts": {
"android": "react-native run-android",
"ios": "react-native run-ios",
"start": "react-native start",
"test": "jest",
"lint": "eslint ."
},
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
"react": "16.9.0",
"react-native": "0.61.5",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.1.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "7.13.15",
"@babel/runtime": "7.13.10",
"@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
"babel-jest": "24.9.0",
"eslint": "6.8.0",
"jest": "24.9.0",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.56.4",
"react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
},
"jest": {
"preset": "react-native"
}
}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. Since we need to install `react-native-reanimated` I did check its docs and they aren't supporting `react-native` < v0.62 and you are using `"react-native": "0.61.5"` in your package.json.

Try upgrading your `react-native` dependency. It worked for me. Good luck!

Reference: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs